# Learning Haskell, Roll Your Own Bot Example

Tags: haskell, bots

I am starting to learn Haskell, and found this program: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Roll_your_own_IRC_bot/Source .

When I enter it, and to to compile using ghc --make 4.hs tutbot I get the following error:

```
4.hs:58:10:
    Couldn't match expected type `() -> IO b0' with actual type `IO ()'
    In the return type of a call of `putStrLn'
    Probable cause: `putStrLn' is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of `bracket', namely `(putStrLn "done.")'
    In the expression:
      bracket
        (printf "Connecting to %s ... " server >> hFlush stdout)
        (putStrLn "done.")
        a
```

This is the code: (I have checked for embedded tabs and ensured all in same comlumn):

```
--
-- Connect to the server and return the initial bot state
-- 
connect :: IO bot
connect = notify $ do
    t <- getClockTime
    h <- connectTo server (PortNumber (fromIntegral port))
    hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
    return (Bot h t)
  where
    notify a = bracket
        (printf "Connecting to %s ... " server >> hFlush stdout)
        (putStrLn "done.")
        a
```

--

I cannot see the problem, and no one else seems have had the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's an API change in `bracket`. It's current type is

```
bracket :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> IO c) -> IO c
```

where the result of the first action (the "opening" action) is passed to both the second and third ones. This way the opening action can return a "key" which is used to close things up during clean up.

In this code snippet however both the `a` and `(putStrLn "done")` fragments are values, not functions. That may have been for an older version of `bracket` with a type like

```
bracket :: IO a -> IO b -> IO c -> IO c
```

This correction may fix the error

```
connect :: IO bot
connect = notify $ \_ -> do
    t <- getClockTime
    h <- connectTo server (PortNumber (fromIntegral port))
    hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
    return (Bot h t)
  where
    notify a = bracket
        (printf "Connecting to %s ... " server >> hFlush stdout)
        (const $ putStrLn "done.")
        a
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the type of `bracket` is

```
IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> IO c) -> IO c
```

So we create a resource with the first `IO a`, attach a cleanup which takes the resource `a` and cleans it up in the second part, and then the main block is third.

But `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` so when applied it's just `IO ()`, not the `() -> IO ()` bracket wants. The same with `a`, neither are functions.

This can easily be fixed with

```
...
  (const $ putStrLn "done")
  (const a)
```

Which just has us ignore that extra argument since we're not cleaning up any resources.

Additionally, type names are always capatilized, so `Bot`, not `bot`

Answer (score 0):

Two small problems. First, look at the type of `bracket`:

```
bracket :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> IO c) -> IO c
```

The first argument is meant to produce a resource, the second to release it, and the third to do something useful with it (that may throw exceptions). So the second and third functions take an argument, which you can ignore:

```
notify a = bracket
    (printf "Connecting to %s ... " server >> hFlush stdout)
    (\_ -> putStrLn "done.")
    (\_ -> a)
```

Second, you’ve written this type signature for `connect`:

```
connect :: IO bot
```

The `bot` here is a type variable; you want `Bot`, a type constructor:

```
connect :: IO Bot
```

Your type signature currently says that `connect` does some I/O and will return a value of *any type*, which it calls `bot`. Clearly that can’t be true!